# Count characters on (keyup) does not work if you view web site on mobile

Tags: angular

Imagine there is a website built using Angular 6.  I have to count characters as user type them in in the text area.  It works ok with (keyup) if the site is viewed NOT on Mobile. Is is because there is no keyboard on the phones?  What is an alternative in this case to use?  Thank you

Tried (oninput)

Answer (score 1):

Try `(input)` event binding like this-

```
<input type="text" (input)="onInput($event)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chzbxl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel" (ngModelChange)="myValueChange($event)" />
    {{lenmodel}}
```

in your .ts

```
  mymodel;
  lenmodel;
  myValueChange(newValue) {
    this.mymodel = newValue;
    this.lenmodel = newValue.length;
    console.log(newValue);
  }
```

Comment: this is not counting the number of characters. only printing the same values

Comment: wait i will give count @natasha

Comment: i have already edited your answer to give count. just approve it